# Deduce Bounded in Probability From Matrix Normalization

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

If we have a $T\times r$ matrix $A$ and we know $$ A'A = T I_r$$

How can we deduce that $$ \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T} \lVert A_t \rVert^2 = O_p(1)$$
where $A_t$ is the transpose of the $t$-th row of $A$. Especially why it is bounded in probability.

My solution is 
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{T} \sum \lVert{A_t}\rVert^2 &= \frac{1}{T} \sum tr{(A_t A_t')} \\
&= \frac{1}{T} tr (\sum A_t A_t') \\
&=\frac{1}{T} Tr = r 
\end{align}

Then it's $O(1)$ and also $O_p (1)$. Is it correct?

The claim is made on page 213 of "Determining the Number of Factors in Approximate Factor Models" (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/1468-0262.00273)